# What are the "source" Items in UI Component Files

Tags: magento2, uicomponent, forms, knockoutjs, requirejs

In Magento 2's UI Form Component configuration files, you'll often see a `item` attribute with the same of `source` -- `<item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>` below.

```
#File: vendor/magento/module-cms/view/adminhtml/ui_component/cms_block_form.xml
<field name="title">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Block Title</item>
            <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>
            <item name="source" xsi:type="string">block</item>
            <item name="sortOrder" xsi:type="number">20</item>
            <item name="dataScope" xsi:type="string">title</item>
            <item name="validation" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="required-entry" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            </item>
        </item>
    </argument>
</field>
```

What are these fields for?  I ask because it *seems like* they're not necessary.  For example, [the module in this GitHub repository](https://github.com/astorm/magento2-pestle-platonic-module-output) [configures a working UI Component form](https://github.com/astorm/magento2-pestle-platonic-module-output/blob/master/app/code/Pulsestorm/Pestleform/view/adminhtml/ui_component/pulsestorm_pestleform_things_form.xml), but doesn't use these `name="source"` items.

Does anyone know what these `name="source"` items are for?  I'm aware of the UI Component mechanic that takes the XML and cofigures it as `x-magento-init` JSON

```
"block_id": {
    "type": "form.input",
    "name": "block_id",
    "dataScope": "block_id",
    "config": {
        "component": "Magento_Ui\/js\/form\/element\/abstract",
        "template": "ui\/form\/field",
        "visible": false,
        "dataType": "text",
        "formElement": "input",
        "source": "block"
    }
},
```

Which is fed into a `uiElement` based Knockout view model object.  However, it's not clear how the nested tree of `uiElement` based Knockout view model objects use these field level `source` fields.

If I look at the `uiElement`'s `initModules` method

```
    initModules: function () {
        _.each(this.modules, function (name, property) {
            if (name) {
                this[property] = this.requestModule(name);
            }
        }, this);

        if (!_.isFunction(this.source)) {
            this.source = registry.get(this.provider);
        }

        return this;
    },
```

I see the object references a `source` property, and if its not set, will reach into the registry for an object using the `provider` property as a string/key identifier.  It **seems like** the value of these `source` items isn't used.  However, its possible that they're used by the PHP code, or some other javascript code.  Hence, my question.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Went to ["the source"](https://community.magento.com/t5/Programming-Questions/What-are-the-source-Items-in-UI-Component-Files/m-p/61799#M1797) (groan) for this one and it looks like these `<item name="source"/>` nodes are, indeed, redundant.  Or, the Magento engineer currently in charge of them thinks they're redundant, so that's as close to truth as we'll get.

Answer (score 8):

The `source` is, or should be, the data provider. From what I can tell, however, the `<item name="source">` node in the XML example you gave makes **no measurable difference** and can be removed without consequence.

Here's how I came to that: in the `initModules()` method of `elements/element.js`, there is a check to see if `this.source` is a callable function:

```
if (!_.isFunction(this.source)) {
    this.source = registry.get(this.provider);
}
```

If `this.source` is not a callable function, it *overrides* `this.source` with a UI Component from the registry using `this.provider`. Again, this is the `provider`, though, and not the `source`. As such, if the source is not a callable function at that point, it simply loads the provider and the original `this.source` goes the way of the wind.

`this.source` often is empty, but in the case of the `cms_block_form`, `this.source` would be `'block'` to start with. Since that is a string and not a callable function, it is simply overridden.

Also note that a UI Component could easily add some logic to set `this.source` to a callable function, based off of a string from XML, before `initModules()` is run.

---

Now, why is this source there in the first place? I don't know why it's in the XML, but it serves a purpose in the Javascript. For an example, I pulled up `grid/columns/column.js`. In `defaults: {}`, the following is there:

```
modules: {
    source: '${ $.provider }'
}
```

Back in `elements/element.js`, this is evaluated in `initModules()`:

```
_.each(this.modules, function (name, property) {
    if (name) {
        this[property] = this.requestModule(name);
    }
}, this);
```

Here is the `requestModule()` method:

```
requestModule: function (name) {
    var requested = this._requesetd;
    if (!requested[name]) {
        requested[name] = registry.async(name);
    }
    return requested[name];
},
```

The `async()` method is returned from the registry, and in `initModules()`, assigned to the property given. In this case, `this.source` is set to be the `async()` method from the registry. This would happen for anything within `modules:{}`, not just `source`, but sheds light on what happens with the `source` in some components. The `async()` function returned from is - not surprisingly - a callable function. As a result, this evaluates to false and is skipped:

```
initModules: function () {
    ...

    if (!_.isFunction(this.source)) {
        this.source = registry.get(this.provider);
    }

    return this;
},
```

Back in `grid/columns/column.js`, `source` is used to change the sorting of the grid.

```
exportSorting: function () {
    ...
    this.source('set', 'params.sorting', {
        field: this.index,
        direction: this.sorting
    });
},
```

The `async()` method handles the functionality, but here, it is calling the `set()` method on `this.source()`. The source, or, `dataProvider`, is `grid/provider.js` and it does not have a `set()` method. It's parent, `element/element.js` does, though:

```
set: function (path, value) {
    var data = this.get(path),
        diffs;

    diffs = !_.isFunction(data) && !this.isTracked(path) ?
        utils.compare(data, value, path) :
        false;

    utils.nested(this, path, value);

    if (diffs) {
        this._notifyChanges(diffs);
    }

    return this;
},
```

The concept with `set()` is somewhat simple in that it updates values and notifies subscribers. So, as a result of `columns.js` declaring a `source`, it has direct access to execute methods on it's `dataProvider`.

---

**Conclusion:** the source appears to be what is used, at least in Javascript classes, as the data provider. If a source is set in a Javascript class, and is a callable function, it can be used to execute methods directly on the `dataProvider`.

This leaves me with a few questions still, though:

- Is it possible to use `source` in XML in order to proxy a dataProvider class?
- Was it supposed to serve a purpose in XML but get deprecated at some point?
- Are there any core classes that look at `this.source` (from XML) and do something interesting with it before `initModules()` is run?

Comment: +1 for useful information, but end up with the same question I have -- what's `source` doing in those XML files :)

Answer (score 3):

The source is the key using which the ui component can read the data provided by "*DataProvider*" class. It is very useful when there are multiple tabs and fieldsets.

For example : refer `module-customer/view/base/ui_component/customer_form.xml`

```
<fieldset name="customer">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Account Information</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="entity_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">text</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>

                **<item name="source" xsi:type="string">customer</item>**

            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
. 
. 
.

<fieldset name="address">
    <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
        <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="is_collection" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
            <item name="label" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Addresses</item>
            <item name="removeMessage" xsi:type="string" translate="true">Are you sure you want to delete this item?</item>
        </item>
    </argument>
    <field name="parent_id">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="visible" xsi:type="boolean">false</item>
                <item name="dataType" xsi:type="string">number</item>
                <item name="formElement" xsi:type="string">input</item>

                **<item name="source" xsi:type="string">address</item>**

            </item>
        </argument>
    </field>
```

The `getData()` method in *DataProvider* class will return an array with keys 'customer' and 'address' and the corresponding fields in the field-sets will be mapped from it. The screen-shot displays the result of `getData()` method.

[image: Output of getData() method of DataProvider class]

Afterwards when the `getDataSourceData()` method in Magento\Ui\Component\Form is called it processes the above data.

```
public function getDataSourceData()
{
    $dataSource = [];

    $id = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam($this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getRequestFieldName(), null);
    $filter = $this->filterBuilder->setField($this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getPrimaryFieldName())
        ->setValue($id)
        ->create();
    $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()
        ->addFilter($filter);

    $data = $this->getContext()->getDataProvider()->getData();

    if (isset($data[$id])) {
        $dataSource = [
            'data' => $data[$id]
        ];
    } elseif (isset($data['items'])) {
        foreach ($data['items'] as $item) {
            if ($item[$item['id_field_name']] == $id) {
                **$dataSource = ['data' => ['general' => $item]];**
            }
        }
    }
    return $dataSource;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for answering. However, are you sure about this?   I'm not sure you're correct.  Yes, on the customer form the JSON data has a key named customer, and that key coincidentally uses the name name as the `<item name="source` node.  However, I don't see any PHP code that references the data in the source node.  Also, the CMS Page form has a `<item name="source" xsi:type="string">page</item>` node and its data source data does not have a `page` key. Finally, my research indicates its `name="dataScope"` that determines where a field gets its values.

Comment: yes,  you are right Alan. During debugging I also saw the same thing (about dataScope). Thanks for the clarification. If I get anything more about "source" I will post.